# Having trouble with my simple alarm clock

Tags: python, clock, python-2.x, alarm

```
#import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from datetime import datetime
from time import strftime
import time

#Setting up GPIO
#GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
#GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN)

#Datetime variables
now_strf = strftime("%I:%M %p")
quest = raw_input("What time would you like to wake up? ")

while True:
    if quest == now_strf:
        print "Ring"
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print now_strf
        time.sleep(1)
```

My problem is it prints "Ring" when i set the alarm for the time it is now, but when I set it for a minute or two later, it doesn't go off. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your `while` loop you're comparing two variables, `quest` and `now_strf`.

The problem is that `now_strf` never changes. You need to update `now_strf` with the current time in every iteration:

```
while True:
    now_strf = strftime("%I:%M %p")
    if quest == now_strf:
        print "Ring"
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I spent way too much time trying to get this to work. Didn't know it was that simple.